# Add Customer And Product Specific Attributes in Asp.Net Storefront

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspdotnetstorefront

I am making changes to existing Asp.net Storefront application. I have two requirements regarding that.

1 ) I want to add customer specific attribute while creating the customer. I.e Is customer a retail customer or a wholesale customer ? How can i add this option on this page ? Is it possible or not ?

[image]

2 ) I want to add product specific attributes. i.e Please take a look at the screen shot.

[image]

there are some predefined attributes for all products. But what if i want to add some other custom attributes ? how can i achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. As i stated i wanted to identify the customer as retailer or Wholesaler and wanted to assign the discount based on the customer type.

I found that we can add the levels for particular customer. and can define several options for that level.

It is available under users ==> Customer levels. Please take a look at the screenshot below.

hope this can help some one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've used a few different e-commerce systems that allowed for custom attributes but I'm not familiar with your screenshots. What is the name of your system?

I recommend you do a search for documentation for whatever your specific e-commerce product is called. If custom attributes is not covered in the docs you should at least be able to find some contact information for customer support.

Comment: i am using http://www.aspdotnetstorefront.com/. I searched on the docs but couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add the additional field within the SQL table and then reference the new field in the relevant .aspx and aspx.cs page that is within your admin folder.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Can you share an example of how to reference that field in aspx page. ?